# Creating a list from series of pandas

Tags: python-3.x, openfoam

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtdi6.png)I m trying to create a list from 3 different series which will be of the shape "({A} {B} {C})" where A denotes the 1st element from series 1, B is for 1st element from series 2, C is for 1st element from series 3 and this way it should create a list containing 600 element.

```
List 1              List 2           List 3
u_p0 1              v_p0 2           w_p0 7
u_p1 21             v_p1 11          w_p1 45
u_p2 32             v_p2 25          w_p2 32
u_p3 45             v_p3 76          w_p3 49
...                 ....             ....
u_p599 56           v_p599 78        w_599 98
```

Now I want the output list as follows

```
    (1 2 7)
    (21 11 45)
    (32 25 32)
    (45 76 49)
.....
```

These are the 3 series I created from a dataframe

```
r1=turb_1.iloc[qw1] #List1
r2=turb_1.iloc[qw2] #List2
r3=turb_1.iloc[qw3] #List3
```

[Pic of the series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs3Dh.png)For the output I think formatted string python method will be useful but I m quite not sure how to proceed.

```
turb_3= ["({A} {B} {C})".format(A=i,B=j,C=k) for i in r1 for j in r2 for k in r3]
```

Any kind of help will be useful.

Comment: Can you post a sample dataframe? Also, is the expected output a list of strings or tuples?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your reply. I m attaching the pic of the main dataframe which contains everything. The 3 list which I posted above belongs to 0 time-step but I need to do the same for the rest time-step too. You can find the pic of the dataframe in the attachment of the post above . Is that fine?

Comment: Please refrain from uploading an image. You can try posting the result of `print(your_data[[qw1, qw2, qw3]].head(5))` and provide an expected output based on the sample ;)

Comment: @Chris I m a very new user of Python , I tried the command which you just mentioned in the previous comment but it is showing some error. I want a list of strings and if there anything you require apart from this just ask me here. :)

Comment: Please take a look at the answer I've posted. While you will have to change the variable names, I hope you get the gist ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.itertuples` with `str.format`:

```
# Sample data
print(df)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     7
1    21    11    45
2    32    25    32
3    45    76    49

fmt = "({} {} {})"

[fmt.format(*tup) for tup in df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].itertuples(False, None)]
```

Output:

```
['(1 2 7)', '(21 11 45)', '(32 25 32)', '(45 76 49)']
```